# Probability of exactly 1 given everything appears

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coupon-collector

I'm trying to figure out the following question, and I'm stuck! It comes from an old PUMaC problem with a partial solution (there's a typo in the one provided on Stack Exchange as well):

Stack Post:

[Collecting cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771737/collecting-cards)

Original Problem and Solution (problem 4):

https://static1.squarespace.com/static/570450471d07c094a39efaed/t/5de43032c573c502d7fe2f7d/1575236145801/2019Combo_A_Sols.pdf

If I'm not mistaken, I think what the problem is saying is that if you have cards $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$, drawn independently and with equal probability 1/6 (uniformly), what is (1 minus) the probability that you obtain exactly one A, given that you stop drawing when you've drawn every card? (We can choose A w.l.o.g. by law of total probability).

e.g. $(A,B,C,D,E,E,F)$, $(B,B,C,C,D,F,F,E,E,A)$ <-- these draws work.

According to their partial solution, it seems not so much of a coincidence that we see the harmonic series as would be in the case if we found E(number of draws until all 6 appear) using linearity of expectation. But, beyond that I'm not sure how they achieved this answer.

When I tried to go about it, it seemed like it would take significant case work (dependent on the number of draws and whether or not A is the last to appear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider pulling cards until you pull $A$ twice. Note that the order of $A$ is equally likely to be the first, second, ..., sixth. Now, condition on the order of $A$, let it be the $n$th unique card. Let us assume that your position $n$ is not equal to $6$. Now, $A$ is again equally likely to be the last card among the remaining $(6 - n)$ cards, giving a probability of $A$ being last $1/(6-n + 1)$.

For $A$ to be drawn once in your scenario, $A$ had to be the last card in the first or the second draw (do you see why?), giving the final answer $(1/6) + (1/6) \sum_{n=1}^5 1/(6-n + 1)$, which matches the formula they gave. I believe they used a different counting argument, but since their solution is incomplete, and this one is simpler, you might as well use this.

As an important side note, I think the better way to think about this problem to understand all the symmetries and independences is by considering a Poisson splitting (that is how I solved it). It is a hard problem without Poisson processes for sure.

Comment: If I understand the punchline: either on the first draw you get (rest of letters,A) which happens 1/6 or on second draw, you sort of restart at A and reconsider A's occurrence among those that have yet to occur. If A's occurrence happens last after the rest of cards are drawn, you have (first set,A,rest,A). "Ignore" the middle A because that single last A is basically its marker, and you have your complete set. The probability A is last in the second draw depends on its position with all positions occurring with p=1/6.

Comment: Yup, the last A there is a marker if you drew all of your other cards in first set + rest! And yes, your last sentence is also precisely correct. Good job!

Comment: Thank you so much! The Poisson splitting was very helpful for visualizing the approach!